# Auto-creating a Youtube playlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube

I have a [list of Youtube links](http://pastebin.com/TqNQ0EWF) that I would like to add to a Youtube playlist. There are too many links though, so I'd rather not do it manually. Plus, I feel like it would be a fun set of Javascript tricks for me to learn!

The Youtube playlist images look like this:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgHrR.png)

I tried to go through the console and use that and whatnot, but I don't know how to handle click events in Javascript (I Googled this extensively, and got some results about something called "DOM" that I don't really understand).

How would I go about doing this process, or, what are some resources that I can look at that would point me in the right direction? I'm fairly new to coding in general.

Comment: I dont understand what you are trying to accomplish? Do you have a web application that you are going to display the list on or what?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the syntax code for a youtube playlist.

```
<iframe width="720" height="405" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID?playlist=VIDEOID_1,VIDEOID_2"frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
```

As per the syntax your code will look like this.

```html
<iframe width="720" height="405" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kU7oWUSXgg8?playlist=FXUAPHPKEnw,idcXJsPPcC0,mnCeGPTo1ps,DTdSFeQ2yVc,7lePlM-4IQQ,BetVjXZJL_s,1P9t08hLaYU,ALYjxDe5U6U,XpHCOi9AG5Q,nVKouZncauY,1iGyhTisX3I,9DpkwD0TqeY,tFb4pNhjPEA,nlpZNEkDqAQ,2uLjj81rPXI,4MDDFKAvgYA,GzKFEx-wsJo,NuroUwdxl1I,47YClVMlthI,59V0HUgze2Y,gCq8FgCbuZU,VXOYm27uDwc,TaJD91MXnTM,q6UyCcPfWEg,WOrH99yonMU,QEHodKKESyg,8CdAfYwEGCI,yKnG_9q4crA,u6IPPf9f_MI,lS5TIcLJXTw,iluv2qBdUZk,A81Z6hGjGJQ,OYIsa_u_C-s,oB9T-bXlMXI,iUhYGrC3elA,AQsZS508688,zF54tio1PtQ,F3Rs6I17RL0,vrRhp9x_Y7g,4BQ6PeyzxDk,prWdFfEF9xg,7KKcb5bDY8k,D67jM8nO7Ag,abHLpk4rn5M,XTN4A3B2Ybk,8Pl1YU1rXuE,7MvzjjPNzsk,H6Q4s_ZdvAQ,MBecuqA-xSk,ZS2UeyksAIU,HkMNOlYcpHg,ZCGhPk9c66U,wPQlxHWsemI,6ROxHLEvsT8,bMKcaftNHuQ,IfStwtztZRY,oWMKzvmmCa8,yA-ee9M_jhE,9aofoBrFNdg,f4hbJ5zh-SQ,9FSVhbuE7Uk,4p39ciSHKwo,Gs069dndIYk,tl3HYz2EIJo,0VZtTye-bWU,mEePSS4IHsE,4-yLbd4O2Ls,5jUGAVUwhRU,cE0B61IarP0,5Bvlfer3Pag,teMpSQaLC1M,7bDLIV96LD4,lDnZjMoUI24,oWYp1xRPH5g,vpVX8CT8-sA,l_4XUUnUGt8,9CFoZwvty4U,8FzkYR6VCfY,BuMBmK5uksg,fBgpCgbt2Yk,LsSQMGhEP_o,acdtvO-yHqQ,SY7PfdUDGHU,etwIu8-FlGU,xHXEarTr5vg,HYu5qVJmlr0,X1JaNKTRMlY,T3IzUftwpyM,2fngvQS_PmQ,VGi10PzL064,MG-ia0NV8Ts,58l0-Jc_bOk,MmuScV9yC-4,FufL80hJsP8,w5TFDMrZBMM,9lovHtxvaXU,xoUVtthd7gY,kjIO_fD_5qs,Z0MbcACY1FI,qzq4znsbiFg,K8IyAfLF1jw,OEHbAo6NFEk,JHxVjii2HYE,nv76KvFV748,adJaPNwIARQ,wNjC3gmVqE0,H2aySTpJ1uY,PbgKEjNBHqM,Kr8R-sOS2OE,aKV-ZLQheaM,RvA3q0ZU-NQ,WcF-LEo2D4I,CHV6BjuQOZQ,B2zrtyqAetw,10WgCJKSJhI,5wQ3VgxOmwI,_o2RS8WfcbY,AYKYvVkhIYo,gDxoZ1Plw1Q,9MErCre5Pjg,YcnvM2Eg_Rc,Lp1fQ51YZMM,QYz-CjqaOG0,iU1L5dP2DhY,vIWL7XLzQkU,3gxNW2Ulpwk,MBf5E0MySHw,dsp5OASh7bg,wpi6JuLV7UE,t3OLviy8f6E,AdBoybKnzZw,6g5ZF6DUrHI,eu2iv-MKT8,sOIt51w6cH8,GWr17KGDi-8,KqULZjSYo5w,u1kgXQTAUBc,0g7EwE6ztlg,7e5-0t0pTF0,Wbq3axLwamE,iZZUY32iCzU,EDEEzS7OV2k,5Fp1viiRJnw,tRZBAvstyxA,Bm-Ijm5X84w,VJKf_-1tF30,K5DPdq3MWWA,d0yA0Q1l2jo,HHOM4udJPEg,Rq7YDEK4quY,oHKpXAPTVNU,uu_zwdmz0hE,O2r1Np2vPnw,krDxhnaKD7Q,O2jj3YbgX_w,3qaYErEtLGI,94MDl3K-wPE,8bhfu1KnKjM,iq_d8VSM0nw,Jozz7RmLpq0,QX5XKFn7Ngo,Q11ium_-Lv8,HU0AHsAmjBQ,esRt0Lca0fw,RpRNjESk1v0,yWWmT_1qs08,WNEfets9J6w,Ih-izudb6Uo,ilmfGaFXWSY,E8pNta0mtw0,9GavnF2SuOc,shkPBPNGSu0,TDX0vIegNrM,_jY16ioQ4DU,_JZom_gVfuw,7silZ8-kcaA,aoBELyv9cgk,kMXxLFlnlic,XHLnM1diUHk,0KueJSKQSGw,3lDqMx4rmFU,WH6xvB7zSRc,F3rAbQjjQAk,QOo8w6J-vks,-YCeIgt7hMs,Y71cx8Vj15Q,A7lxd7RL1To,uPOUgobWTT0,gyAmXB9LQvI,nprhOpgoNCc,W35hex44roE,76WJJ57YoG0,CRHyBwNtkLA,_8yGGtVKrD8,2oyhlad64-s,gTH7XefE85A,pJk0p-98Xzc,6vopR3ys8Kw,Ji-fqHtviOU,AW6rCm5980g,rvsXshjNVLU,yB8Ci7X5HUU,M11SvDtPBhA,RKenP4KLQLo,k66w45Iz7cc,AcbzBQ7L6A0,6Dakd7EIgBE,fw1My4WtcDc,KqHxOC_kCP0,QFfZ1kfiAEs,HOQa8CU3yXw,rLniANe7UtA,mJ_fkw5j-t0,h2zgB93KANE,Fv_mSzxO70c,LkeBPgszdoM,nc853HK0p8M,ifOW2kPKhV4,TGfP9MFFgIE,H_HPocmnLsg,sclfhlScwkk,Xi1_GYahCSs,450p7goxZqg,9I9Ar6upx34,45lCeMVrCJM,aoBELyv9cgk,QYLIs5SIST4,r1zDNAR4sJ4,OA2VdKzdjfM,7LnEeRidcXw,5sVqGYXBVG0,jNJMzWI573M,qNRhMIFjd64,03MXhKZqG9Y,7HTJaJuA0Gw,FvU0i3gvtxc,7TCvLpAB11o,-JwNZs9eecE,2ji6sJLFc8A,4xKxhXH-sZ0,ZPPPfgdYT2M,j2jCxHdG7W8,mL5yuxvLCwU,_oB78dvtNKs,woT7wos_ibY,NaIDj6vBEoU,RKtOVe6zAqU,VqOgJrvnJvg,ah5zfje7iGY,8CPlF-IEkXQ,7KJjVMqNIgA,hJfkyMCOsl4,sAouQH-34hs,moSFlvxnbgk,8iE9G6EWYB0,BNeM4zwadt0,dwUug-ucBLc,oU0ZmbBY9QI,9j9EEWavHhY,3AZAo3Ia7DE,2a2Snz43Nj4,J5TMPEfH2eg,izBjrTV-8LY,-kadw8va9oo,lqVvHAFPIrw,TxTT0PbodU4,5WDjBivzEog,ajXRTNsoOlg,pKfrBvIxA08,w1Z-V2xey-Q,93I7fObG66M,-qz9Fjn_FRg,fKLWC_LokdE,uPwuduhx0vw,mEcja_hOV1Y,IDM1wUM-dCk,p6vAn25I4h4,7fkOqXAHLKQ,RHmhC80_Bzg,FPLvD7Yz__c,9sdtOpE_3aQ,wWt1qh67EnA,ycHluR67jiY,ETpioCTGj7M,ErYAGQZs8e0,CMfrXXTvfd8,rfevr472lSU,i2HnH86mVpo,_DtRNRH6nP4,N6KBfGRvDx4,LFI9TIp7qRA,bbCT6_HAOmM,JAHA4Jh5jkw,qS2yMn3JbQk,DTHC6bL_ZtE,O4iyH-oBNPk,WrO9PTpuSSs,b6Me6szvLvw,qKxDzyHPo0o,tG35R8F2j8k,bbq016ZOWYw,9p-SnAC8U_k,smnxo-qwzdA,kGWrv7Ngtec,WZY6eLFkFPs,tNkysKTy638,UaN5O7pym6A,OPkWYTUiPTo,wp-KfrCInfo,olYK5OQW_nc,lPMDciiU10E,6okxuiiHx2w,mN1SSb_zP0w,KW_6XpVfgKs,apN0AXjJxQE,lKAEj6o5PFM,N3KLTgoyjpo,diHc6KH_rbc,FiOcVWQY2bc,sYyu5vbwvbA,VOXw1xz-c8w,6h6AabkLvEE,vh5I5ToqjVk,m5vw4ajnWGA,-ZJFYjdZxo,T_saCPs9-0E,rfQqh7iCcOU,lgaRjBXi1NY,5YQ7ePwX7Gk,Pv-Do30-P8A,51e1gIkzHgk,1s9Xs6wEZHc,2SDV6FFch8E,Pi58TuO0xFw,8Q52r7xMd3U,0jgrCKhxE1s,vSaN_tRAkOo,KfHCHgWusHM,2t2xRcS5Q9o,1p-ujE4g_k,tVIYIy3F-UI,caUc3vA9Wh8,ObUREzucuW8,vfT-X7mVRvI,DtyfiPIHsIg,D81HT_FSbgE,l-O5IHVhWj0,0tVus4ujVVY,6Bd4mks_hWo,3MteSlpxCpo,1HIWuh-6Dfc,BO-artgNHHQ,q8mWZxEOlnQ,Q1YX_M0wt-Y,qYMNbeYPwC4,pBiFel99JEM,bwnpDxAgcO4,VBmCJEehYtU,yYvqZjWuls4,0NUX4tW5pps,0VqTwnAuHws,Fryur0Z5AOY,x-64CaD8GXw,2pE-OwC1aes,YKY1_PlOZgc,8htJVyavMvo,kJizV-d3sEQ,NBVJuA0jr6Y,FPTp-YInbJ0,B_SqHT2cjKU,HpGezZY5boE,Y-S-vEz0F_o,nnp-FYRXIR0,_izLPAmdeWM,vbxcPy1qJTU,RadTrClPxxg,903A5ijQveE,PeQWPRtxn-s,N1yGG8jMSTI,FvcyZOVCORM,N4HPFAds7bc,a2CGMyzZj6Y,wMSDPLOSHyQ,EJypM3gww4k,zu7hYbw0x3Y,JTEFKFiXSx4,gRwFRMGpTWg,JzPTXhd5fQM,JOD-M7WZkZQ,GHC8Hwq9Eag,L9TvN82Zf1o,9jWazCsHjqY,hTdopxNeuaU,cs6rxYEvrns,fj7sVX0ZqXc,cMekH3_5h6g,keT37f01S-s,XKqtYlsOJrU,x5Cbi_u_aLQ,UW1QGrRmRQ4,hmG5XakkyxM,Dg9sEe8u0Lk,e6NjqujEy1o,6903zFUIxoU,5S6U_krabrk,qai_HtFEI0g,Z59QNcX880c,p_mHZrOWONM,tYdeKTOyh8c,XwF2aEzp3Fw,B_SqHT2cjKU,wpqm-05R2Jk,wi9j7Jeafoc,BpqNvskS_kM,4g03b4U_aPk,ebM0KRDRRa4,eXvBjCO19QY,LzDazRBqVZU,1OsI6vXZAQM,LWhr6Uk1K1E,L7emX-6VwTs,2daor2cv264,GZ3DWnkILbY,6nS1rcSo8oI,9nth2LHK6CU,EG4NTfgUk0Y,Wilq6yYy5fo,ZUPp5YjbSdQ,gvEGaIAq8kI,1vViTMfQo2o,fPEsDF5WL1w,_fTvmsutsw8,33YcYLumEDk,uOxrrWEcThw,zo0OccO5_qU,7DFId0KffBY,CZwfjupFJ_U,tgbNymZ7vqY,JXhAz0DOpMU,hwyQgl3nc2s,cFLN66d5lMA,OHTSxw6zN1E,ZemLVg8gylw,OBl4pp0Sfko,BrXZpSVUY3k,WF34N4gJAKE,zNK7WO7_lDA,d1LAOQKwD54,RUkqD00RgGw,GFOeJOtq_xc,jiiFzKfuPMk,B72W-pRW_XY,JwxK2QsMKeU,AdZK0HeYkwM,wUrZNG7v5nA,nv_7NctzxAg,dgthmCrvYMk,E1x7AeEogGM,dESxO9ITMO4,r3-7Y0xG89Q,PSUUFduCdRE,9XJZpHPxSUw,UUPCBmcpNzk,Hq0tPjdfHME,UKjj4hk0pV4,ceemvObxR7o,0VwfYCFYZws,8XpNY5SPC5Q,kTqsU7tQW48,tIKQqvt-sWM,Q8m_ZuFEQUM,OIRE6iw-ws4,9fAZIQ-vpdw,h2zWfxW60z0,fb8M8rMMhK0,I6HP3iZcuUo,NT9xGJvW13c,s8Gf0TzygLc,Do5MMmEygsY,Es7rds2402U,VBmEJZofz2s,Y-RxVudVuo4,9PXO05s4z3Q,6rAo3UBI49Y,MjgQLEZ6vjY,__-Qq4IE5pw,jHdi9JFcmb0,ULScfJm-tWE,Z4tacX_LGYg,XEZXjW_s0Qs,aELKWhMootE,h8IeT5yLAyg,cY5n8SgJ8hY,UawFeEwJCgA,X1uelY2SGmw,5KML7KN6hpI,QHMrJNZaatE,Yu4KObwynSc,INlPqwl473I,61OE1JhhTg8,crHBzIYRjdY,7IUYZV4ijt8,cRqmWW_QTSU,N9qYF9DZPdw,MEQMkzjcLEA,x7IefVX3wWw,Bk5F_S4p9Ic,GEUpQ5pCSOQ,X1uelY2SGmw,S2XswIp78aM,o9PuAm7d0PA,-w-58hQ9dLk,lefCeOzfzsc,X2WH8mHJnhM,a2k9fgGDdQQ,9WpApbC1rfg,jfTDdqhMocU,pq28qCklEHc,vHfdd-PQVwo,JAtFvNEPPmI,Gk5DC-qwXw,pG7_gceIFL4,6mXpkrT8BT8,32X-ieCav-M,ytl6LFlE3GE,gC6LguIleH8,-POmAga8EAs,hYqEHyrLVo4,AnLQuBHngW4,x7CIgWZTdgw,wP7V9l5hc08,nPQj2s7R5S4,RTREDvH8H4g,zMlSdRmFdeI,6diDVdaUxuQ,toyvffrYBkw,0Yeb3q5nqWA,bYrmop7g2cU,2nzQMHLk6LA,Vois0RMtPHE,yO7MWuJ7zLA,iRGruntGgnU,URpjQySdluA,uLH-QIFWx_g,M-Ih38AlD3Q,6ZoPdGgATIA,44slfjV3l48,tCr79zXor24,sNtuFgwU988,wNC9KVDQtas,CJbI-5kkkqc,SAMB01JK5pY,uWu4aynBK7E,EJ8yKvgGyDw,8m5CIcbytfM,yKZN5ydm2U8,8M_XETcoHE4,HilGthRhwP8,uaQZ9fQDAlU,OYG1iQoil8w,pNhgQepfIY8,99pEsiqxFzY,0fg08Hjwdo0,zd449MCw43o,neacjPKTZng,RPh2seGKDG0,v4DTR0I7xhA,UdsuKwxwbrM,y7B9i0IKIcA,5839cJa3Inw,BGfE-mbdmXg,bE8sjRUjiUI,lJeAzyuTuUI,apiq3VN2Ra8,P5-2-jD-42Q,Ndv9ecwOpjk,7qH4qyi1-Ys,jcSVmRtby38,vTYKOkSJHbc,49rw1E3unMA"frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
```

Unfortunately youtube don't support these much videos to be in a playlist(over 500). If you cut short it to below 200 this will work.